# Querying associated records using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model `Tippani`, which belongs to another model `Fiscal Year`.

**Tippani.rb**

```
class QuotationTippani < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fiscal_year
end
```

I have two instances of **tippani** class, that belong to the same fiscal year.

I want to get the instances of tippani class that belongs to the same fiscal year.

I tried something like this:

```
 Tippani.where(fiscal_year_id == 4)
```

But I get an error

> undefined local variable or method `fiscal_year_id' for main:Object

Also, is there some query method, where I could get all the **tippani** instances, whose fiscal year is less than 2073 or some number.

Something like this:

```
Tippani.fiscal_year.where(year < 2074)
```

Comment: In your `FiscalYear` model do you have `has_many quotationtippanis` ?

Comment: Yes, I do have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `Hash` into your query method, like this:

```
QuotationTippani.where(fiscal_year_id: 4)
```

or, if you have `FiscalYear` instance available and `Fiscalyear#quotation_tippanies` association is set up:

```
fiscal_year.quotation_tippanies
```

About the filtering by `year`, it's about using `joins` and passing parameters properly:

```
QuotationTippani.joins(:fiscal_year).where('fiscal_years.year < ?', 2074)
```

Generally speaking, I advice you to read this guide:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

You'll find all the information you need here.

Answer (score 1):

You need `joins`

```
Tippani.joins(:fiscal_year).where(fiscal_years: { id: 4 })
```

Second question also can be handled in similar way.

```
Tippani.joins(:fiscal_year).where("fiscal_years.year < ?", 2074)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: *`where(fiscal_years: { id: 4 })`

Answer (score 1):

`==` is the comparison [operator](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/07/ruby-operators/). When you write:

```
Tippani.where(fiscal_year_id == 4)
```

Ruby treats `fiscal_year_id` as an identifier and tries to find either a local variable or a method named `fiscal_year_id` and checks if it is equal to 4. So even if you had assigned `fiscal_year_id` you're calling:

```
Tippani.where(true) # or false
```

Which isn't even close since you want evaluate `WHERE tippanis.fiscal_year_id = 4` in the database.

[Hashes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html) in Ruby use hashrockets (`=>`) or colons (`:`):

```
# you can assign any type of key with hashrockets
{ :foo => :bar, 1 => "first", true => "yes", false => "no" }
# colons coerce the keys to symbols
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, "this gets cast to a symbol": 4 }
```

Colons are generally preferred. When you call a method you can omit the braces as long as the hash is the last argument.

```
Tippani.where({ :fiscal_year_id => 4 }) # lots of noise
Tippani.where(fiscal_year_id: 4) # better
```

> Also, is there some query method, where I could get all the tippani
>   instances, whose fiscal year is less than 2073 or some number.
>
> Something like this:
>
> `Tippani.fiscal_year.where(year < 2074)`

Again this won't work since `<` is an operator and the result of evaluating the expression is true or false.

ActiveRecord does not really have an elegant way of handling LT, GT, LTE and GTE conditions. So you either need to use a string:

```
Tippani.joins(:fiscal_year).where('fiscal_years.year < ?', 2074)
```

Or use [Arel](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/using-arel-to-compose-sql-queries):

```
Tippani.joins(:fiscal_year).where(FiscalYear.arel_table[:year].lt(2074))
```

Comment: I would really recommend that you learn the language first before trying to learn Rails.